# ASP.NET MVC: Order of execution of ValueProviders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, value-provider

I like to know the order of the execution of the different `ValueProviders` in ASP.NET MVC.

ValueProviders:

- QueryStringValueProvider
- RouteDataValueProvider
- FormValueProvider
- ...

I did not find an information.

Comment: How about this?
ASP.NET MVC / Web API / Web Pages - Source Code http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e599230bf8ac#src/System.Web.Mvc/ValueProviderFactories.cs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If memory serves me, the priority is like this.

1. Form data in the request
2. Route data
3. Query String
4. Http File Collection

**EDIT**
I appear to be in agreement with the following website, which lists the same order.
http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/TheBeautyThatIsTheModelBinder

Answer (score 4):

You can check this out from ASP.NET MVC source code: [ValueProviderFactories.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ValueProviderFactories.cs)

Here is the predefined order for ValueProviders:

```
    private static readonly ValueProviderFactoryCollection _factories = new ValueProviderFactoryCollection()
    {
        new ChildActionValueProviderFactory(),
        new FormValueProviderFactory(),
        new JsonValueProviderFactory(),
        new RouteDataValueProviderFactory(),
        new QueryStringValueProviderFactory(),
        new HttpFileCollectionValueProviderFactory(),
    };
```